# How to clear or reset the nginx cache when a request other than GET is made?

Tags: nginx, caching

Currently my api works with nginx and I have a cache with a duration of 30s, the problem is that when I make any modification the change is seen until the cache expires that is after the 30s. How can I make so that the cache is cleared when the query is different than GET?

Here is my nginx configuration file

```
fastcgi_cache my_zone;
fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;  


server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    
    server_name server.name;

    #Cache everything by default
    set $no_cache 0;

    # Only cache GET requests
    if ($request_method != GET){
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;

        fastcgi_cache  my_zone;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;          
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
        
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    }

}
```